# Compile Java JAR without Kotlin dependencies?

Tags: java, kotlin, shadowjar

I have Kotlin project with JAR executable as output.
Is it possible to have this final JAR Java only?
I mean by that if I can compile Kotlin into pure Java so I do not need to include Kotlin dependencies in my JAR, because they are very big (almost no code = 800kB)

[image]

Comment: What kind of jar are you trying to create? Since this is tagged as shadowjar I would interpret it as you trying to create a fat/uberjar, where you have to include the stdlib for obvious reasons. Also you don't compile kotlin to java, you compile both to java/JVM bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

If by "dependencies" you mean Kotlin stdlib, you can exclude it by setting `kotlin.stdlib.default.dependency=false` in `gradle.properties` ([Dependency on the standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library)). But how do you think Kotlin classes will be resolved at runtime?